# Test the convergence of the integral $\int_0^1 x^x dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Test the convergence of the integral $\int_0^1 x^x dx$.

I could not show any work because I couldn't di anything about it. I tried to convert it to $\int_0^1 e^{x \ln x} dx$ but from here what should I do?

Please help

Comment: A natural thing to try would be to bound the logarithm. Can you show the bound  $\ln(x) \leq x -1$ for $x > 0$?

Comment: Yes I can but what about the discontinuity of the integrand at x=0. We do have to deal with it right?

Comment: there is no discontinuity there. Even if there was, since the integral remains the same if you redefine the integrand on a finite set of points, if you can bound the integrand at every point but one, that gives you a bound of the integral.

Comment: Yes I understood it. I missed it at first that it's not even a improper integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use l'Hôpital to prove that
$$
\lim_{x\downarrow 0} \ln(x)x = \lim_{x\downarrow 0} \frac{\ln(x)}{\frac{1}{x}} = 0.
$$
Therefore $\displaystyle \lim_{x \downarrow 0} e^{x\ln(x)} = 1$.

So the integrand has a continuous extension onto the compact set $[0, 1]$. In this case, the integral always exists as the integrand has a maximum on the bounded set $[0, 1]$.

Comment: So it's not even a improper integral. Thanks...I feel so stupid.

Comment: Happens to all of us

Comment: One thing I want to know, why did u say that the integrand has a continuous extension? Isn't the integrand just continuous on the interval?

Comment: It is continuous on $(0, 1]$ and not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: Oh I understand. But it's really crazy that even though it's not defined at $x=0$ desmos is still showing it has value $1$ at $x=0$

Comment: Interesting. I do not exactly know how Desmors works but I guess that it is a numerical calculator. So it probably approximates and thus gets 1. But note this: $x^x$ is rigorously defined as $e^{x\ln(x)}$. And this makes no sense at $x=0$ - although the limit exists and equals to 1.

Comment: Yes ofcourse it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Matlab also says that $0^0$ is $1$.

Comment: I think they all are approximating. I never used them much though before.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^1 x^x\,dx = \int_0^1 e^{x \ln x} dx$
Now, use $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...$ 
$\int_0^1 x^x dx =\int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(xln(x))^n}{n!}$

In this case you can interchange summation and integration
$\int_0^1 x^x dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{(xln(x))^n}{n!}$

Now, using the substitution $u=-ln(x)$ you should get 
$$ \int_0^1 x^x\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}$$